# custom adapter view (with pics)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layout

I am trying to create a layout that looks like the following:

[image: the look that i'm trying to achieve]

The words that are typed into the EditText and dynamically parsed and displayed as their own TextView(s) in the AdapterView. If nothing is entered into the EditText, the AdapterView will be empty as well. If there are too many words to fit on one line, they are added to the next line. In the end you get a "brick wall" of TextViews filling up the adapter.

I am having a heck of a time finding any guides on how to achieve this look. I'd like to define as much stuff in XML as possible. I am envisioning something like this:

```
<!-- Activity.xml -->
<RelativeLayout>
     <TextView>
     <EditText>
     <AdapterView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

but none of the existing adapters (ListView,GridView) really fit what I am trying to do here.

Can anyone give me some examples to study?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for your answers, but I decided to answer my own question, as there are a few additional details that I felt were important.

Unfortunately all this will still not produce the look that I described in the original question. For that we will require a custom layout (which I am now working on), however without doing so, this is about as close as we're going to get.

**This example will show you how to populate a GridView (type of AdapterView) with custom elements (Text+Icon in this case)**

xml for main activity

```
<!-- Item.xml -->
<RelativeLayout>
   <TextView>
   <EditText>
   <GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

xml file for the item that will be added to the adapter.

```
<!-- Item.xml -->
<RelativeLayout>
   <TextView>
   <ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

a custom layout class, watch this (only the first 10 mins or so) before implementing: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {

    //members
    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv;
        ImageView iv;
    }
    private LayoutInflater m_Inflater;
    private ArrayList<Object> m_UnderlyingData;

    // context - context
    // _resource - view defined in xml (will be added to adapter view)
    // itemList - data to fit into view from resource
    public MyAdapter(final Context _context, final int _resource, final ArrayList<Object> _itemList) {    
        super(_context, _resource, _itemList);

        m_Inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        m_UnderlyingData = _itemList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        ViewHolder oHolder;

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = m_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.word_item, null);

            // -- remember views that make up the item layout
            oHolder = new ViewHolder();
            oHolder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_word);
            oHolder.iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_icon);

            // -- reference to views that can be accessed outside of this class
            convertView.setTag(oHolder);
        }else{
            oHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //set new data
        oHolder.tv.setText((String) m_UnderlyingData.get(position));
        oHolder.iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And this is the code to use in the activity:

```
GridView oWordGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.myGrid);
ArrayList<Object> oArrayList = new ArrayList<Object>();
oArrayList.add("abc");
oArrayList.add("def");
oArrayList.add("blah");
ListAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.word_item, oArrayList);
oWordGrid.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

### PS

Here is some more edumacational material:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYtB6mlu7vA

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to create a list that has a custom look, then you are correct, the base listview adapters are inadequate.  You need to create your own.

You can do this by creating a class that extends ArrayAdapter and an xml view predefined with your definition above:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ExampleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {

    private int resource;
    private LinearLayout layoutItem;

    public ExampleAdapter(Context context, int _resource, ArrayList<Object> itemList) {     
        super(context, _resource, itemList);        
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        try{

            //****************************************************
            // instantiate the layout
            //****************************************************
            if(convertView == null){
                layoutItem = new LinearLayout(getContext());
                String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
                LayoutInflater vi;
                vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(inflater);
                vi.inflate(resource, layoutItem, true);         
            }else{
                layoutItem = (LinearLayout) convertView;
            }


            //****************************************************
            // bind the layout controls
            //****************************************************
            TextView myTextView = (TextView)layoutItem.findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
            // extend to other view controls...

            //****************************************************
            // use the item object to get information about it
            //****************************************************          
            int Id = item.get_id();


            // do whatever else you need to the display of the layout




            return layoutItem;

        }catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
        }       

}
```

Now instead of calling the base adapter, you would call your custom adapter passing in the list of items that need to be displayed with the layout resource.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, GridView is the best solution since it can auto-wrap to next line if there's not enough space.

You do not use AdapterView directly, use one of the subclasses (such GridView) and a BaseAdapter that does return TextViews from getView to each word.